# Unix SQLLDR scipt gives 'Unexpected End of File' error

Tags: unix, sqlplus, etl, sql-loader

All, I am running the following script to load the data on to the Oracle Server using unix box and sqlldr. Earlier it gave me an error saying sqlldr: command not found. I added "SQLPLUS < EOF", it still gives me an error for unexpected end of file syntax error on line 12 but it is only 11 line of code. What seems to be the problem according to you.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES='ls *.txt'
CTL='/blah/blah1/blah2/name/filename.ctl'

for f in $FILES
do
    cat $CTL | sed "s/:FILE/$f/g" >$f.ctl
    sqlplus ID/'PASSWORD'@SERVERNAME << EOF sqlldr SCHEMA_NAME/SCHEMA_PASSWORD control=$f.ctl data=$f EOF
done
```

Comment: shellter - Thanks for your comment. I tried it both ways, still fails. Any further suggestion? I did the following: <<EOF and closing EOF with no leading spaces or tabs but on the next line (Error: SQLPLUS : command not found). Also, with <<-EOF and indented closing EOF (Error: Unexpected end of line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqlplus` will never know what to do with the command `sqlldr`. They are two complementary cmd-line utilities for interfacing with Oracle DB.

Note NO `sqlplus` or `EOF` etc required to load data into a schema:

```
#!/bin/bash
#you dont want this FILES='ls *.txt'
CTL_PATH=/blah/blah1/blah2/name/'
CTL_FILE="$CTL_PATH/filename.ctl"
SCHEMA_NM=SCHEMA_NAME
SCHEMA_PSWD=SCHEMA_PASSWORD

for f in *.txt 
do
    # don't need cat! cat $CTL | sed "s/:FILE/$f/g" >"$f".ctl
    sed "s/:FILE/$f/g" "$CTL_FILE" > "$CTL_PATH/$f.ctl"
    #myBad sqlldr "$SCHEMA_NAME/$SCHEMA_PASSWORD" control="$CTL_PATH/$f.ctl" data="$f"
    sqlldr $SCHEMA_USER/$SCHEMA_PASSWORD@$SERVER_NAME control="$CTL_PATH/$f.ctl" data="$f" rows=10000 direct=true errors=999

done
```

Without getting too philosophical, using assignments like `FILES=$(ls *.txt)` is a bad habit to get into. By contrast, `for f in *.txt` will deal correctly for files with odd characters in them (like spaces or other syntax breaking values). BUT the other habit you **do want to get into** is to quote all variable references (like `$f`), with dbl-quotes : `"$f"`, OK? ;-) This is the otherside of protection for files with spaces etc embedded in them.

In the **edit update**, I've varibalized your CTL_PATH and CTL_FILE. I think I understand your intent, that you have 1 std CTL_FILE that you pass thru `sed` to create a table specific .ctl file (a good approach in my experience). Note that  you don't need to use `cat` to send a file to `sed`, but your use to create a altered file via redirection (`> $f.ctl`) is very `shell`-like too.

In 2nd **edit update**, I looked here on S.O. and found an example `sqlldr` cmdline that has the correct syntax and have modified to work with your variable names.

To finish up,

- A. Are you sure the Oracle Client package is installed on the machine
  that you are running your script on?
- B. Is the /path/to/oracle/client/tools/bin included in your working
  `$PATH`?

  - C. try `which sqlldr`. If you don't get anything, either its not
    installed or its not in the path.
  - D. If not installed, you'll have to get it installed.
  - E. Once installed, note the directory that contains the `sqlldr` cmd.
    `find / -name 'sqlldr*'` will take a long time to run, but it will
    print out the path you want to use.
  - F. Take the "path" part of what is returned (like
    `/opt/oracle/11.2/client/bin/` (but not the `sqlldr` at the end), and
    edit script at 2nd line with

(Txt added to appease the S.O. Formatter ;-) )

```
export ORCL_PATH="/path/you/found/to/oracle/client"
export PATH="$ORCL_PATH:$PATH"
```

These steps should solve any remaining issues. If this doesn't work, see if there is someone where you work that understands your local computing environment that can help explain any missing or different steps.

IHTH

Comment: Thank you again. I am using FILES=$(ls *.txt) as I have multiple text files and I am inserting the name of the text files in one of the designated fields (in Oracle table) which is specified in a generic control file stated in CTL='/blah/blah1/blah2/name/filename.ctl'. Is it still not the correct way?

Comment: Wow, thank you. I just added @servername and also tried it before without it. Both times it is giving sqlldr: command not found.. any other thoughts?

Comment: @shelter, hats off to you. This was exactly the problem. I had to go to my unix server and change my .bash_profile and add the export path that you mentioned. It solved my problem. Thanks a bunch!!